# No action occurred when clicking on Edite button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, crud

i'm trying to edit a row (my project is a simple phone book)from my index view which shows all of my records (Contact) but when i click on the edit button nothing happens

this is my delete method

```
#region [- Delete -]

    #region [- Get -]

    [HttpGet]
    //  [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? _id, Models.EF_Model.Phone_book _model)
    {
        return View();
    }
    #endregion

    #region [- Post -]

    [HttpPost]
    //[HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete(Models.EF_Model.Phone_book _Model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Ref_ViewModel = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
            Ref_ViewModel.Delete(_Model.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Massage = "Choose a Contact";
        }
        return View(_Model);
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
```

this is my edit method in my Home controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? _id)
    {
        if (_id==null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent); 
        }
        else
        {
            Ref_ViewModel = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
            return View(Ref_ViewModel.Select(_id));
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel.DTO.Contact Ref_Contact)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Ref_ViewModel = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
            Ref_ViewModel.Edit(Ref_Contact, Ref_Contact.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Choose a Contact";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

this is it's view(Contact class is a simple DTO class)

```
@model Phone_Book.ViewModel.DTO.Contact

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Num, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Num, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Num, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

this is my index view

```
@model IEnumerable<Phone_Book.Models.EF_Model.Phone_book>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Data is not updated in database or `Edit` method on POST is not invoked?

Comment: when i press the edit button it's supposed to get to edit page but instead it'll show the index page

Comment: What do you mean _from my index view_? The methods and the view you have shown is for the `Edit()` method. What does you `Index` view have to do with it?

Comment: it's a view which shows all of my records

Comment: What happens when you click on the "Details" button? Is it working or is it like the Edit?

Comment: i wrote nothing behind the details but my delete button works

Comment: Could you show what you wrote on the Delete method of your controller?

Comment: @antoinedelia done

Comment: @MostafaBouzari Now in your Edit method, try writing `return View();` just like in your Delete method and tell me if it works.

Comment: @antoinedelia it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Edit method in your HomeController, try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? _id)
{
    if (_id==null)
    {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent); 
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to show it's data befor editing ? or not

Comment: Yes. If you want to do that, get the info of your Contact from your database and send it to your View.

Comment: how can i do that?my project is 3 tier (model,viewmodel,view)

Comment: Do you have a database connection in your controller?

Comment: Then where do you get your contacts from?

Comment: from viewmodel which is connected to my model(model is connected to DB)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125346/discussion-between-antoinedelia-and-mostafa-bouzari).

Answer (score -1):

From your Home/Index View make a link to **edit** action of your HomeController

### Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Phone_Book.ViewModel.DTO.Contact>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";

}
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Num</th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var contact in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@contact.Num</td>
            <td>@contact.FName</td>
            <td>@contact.LName</td>
            <td>@contact.Address</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = contact.Id}) </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```